# How can i get requestId from facebook api when i invite someone

Tags: facebook

I want to use facebook unity sdk to achieve the function that can invite new player from my facebook friends.I can't find how to get requestid if the friend click the notify then he go to appstore and download the game.

I already know i can get all requests from facebook by using me/appresquest function,but it is not my wonder.I just want get a definite requestid so I can only get one invter to give him reward when a friend click the notify who send to.the facebook just say "When a recipient accepts a request on a mobile platform, this will deep-link to the app. An additional parameter will be present in the loading of the app, the request ID." 
I coundn't find any ways to get the purpose.From the docs,I guess the requestId will be sent to ios or Android when the new user click the notify,then the player download the game.the os will give the requestId if the player first open the app,the facebook Unity SDK could get the requestId,so the developer could get it from SDK.but is that right?i don't know,and i want to know how to get it.
Please help me (some question is so far from now,i think it's out of time,please give me the lateset advices)

Comment: Can you share some code?

Comment: there is no code,I don't know how to do that,I just can get all requestId.that's normal function.